# Error al insertar en Mysql desde Sql Server2014 con SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Estoy utilizando un Integration Services con VS 2013 y Sql Server 2014 quiero exportar datos de una tabla de Sql Server a Mysql pero me da un error ya probe exportar a otra base de datos en Sql Server y tambien a execel 2016 y no tube ningun problema busque y vi que se tenia que poner en true la opcion de retainsameconnection pero sigo sin poder insertar los datos ya que si le indico que me cree una tabla nueva si la hace en Mysql pero no inserta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No lo hace, pero tira algun error?

Comment: Agrega por favor el error arrojado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que tengas que agregar un componente de Data Conversion para convertir los tipos de datos y hacerlo compatibles entre los dos motores de base de datos.

Comment: Gracias probare espero funcione